# Site mult-lingua com expressões regulares

Tags: php, url, php-7, url-amigável

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou com um problema para fazer a identificação da página com a língua ao mesmo tempo. Só esta puxando o index com as línguas e as demais páginas não.

Esse é a expressão da url: **main.php**

```
$urlpatterns = array(
    '/' => 'index.php',
    '/(?P<lang>\S+)' => 'index.php',
    '/(?P<lang>\S+)/quem-somos' => 'quem-somos.php',
    '/(?P<lang>\S+)/contato' => 'contato.php'
);
```

E esse é a configuração do **tradutor.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) { 
    $lang = explode("/", $_GET['lang']);

    if ($lang[0] == "br") { $lang[0] = "br"; require_once ('br.php'); } 
    if ($lang[0] == "en") { $lang[0] = "en"; require_once ('en.php'); } 
    if ($lang[0] == "es") { $lang[0] = "es"; require_once ('es.php'); } 

} elseif (!isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    require_once ('br.php');
}
```

Na URL fica dessa maneira:
meusite.com.br/**br** ou meusite.com.br/**br/**

Porém só busca a página inicial, quando busco por meusite.com.br/**br**/quem-somos ou meusite.com.br/**en**/quem-somos, não busca.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Se eu formatar tudo no **tradutor.php**, as expressões serão ignoradas no **main.php**?

Comment: Bom, sua expressão para o idioma é `(?P<lang>\S+)`, que basicamente é qualquer sequência com um ou mais caracteres que não são espaços em branco. A URL `/en/quem-somos` é uma sequência de mais de um caractere que não são espaços em branco, logo o arquivo exibido deve ser `index.php`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi. O que eu devo retirar dessa minha expressão para funcionar? Pra identificar o en separado de quem-somos: en**/**quem somos?

Comment: Indicando que `lang` não deve possuir `/` no valor, por exemplo, `(?P<lang>[^/]+)`. Isso definirá "lang" como qualquer sequência de um ou mais caracteres que não são a barra. Você pode editar a expressão para ignorar outros caracteres também se desejado.

Comment: Quando uso essa forma acaba dando erro aqui no meu código na linha do preg_match(): 

`
function url_response($urlpatterns) {
  foreach ($urlpatterns as $pcre => $app) {
    if(preg_match("@^{$pcre}$@", REQUEST_URI, $_GET)) {
      include(APPLICATION_DIR.'/'.$app);
      exit();
    } else {
      $erro = true;
    }
  }
  if(isset($erro) && $erro == true){
    include("app/404.php");
  }
  return;
}
`

Comment: Que erro seria esse?

Comment: Deu certo eu acabei tirando um parenteses na minha edição. Funcionou como esperei.
Obrigado pela ajuda!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na expressão regular que está utilizando. Você definiu `lang` como `(?P<lang>\S+)`, porém o `\S` casa com qualquer caractere diferente dos espaços em branco (`' '`, `\n`, `\t`, etc).

Assim, a URL `/en/quem-somos` acaba sendo interpretada inteiramente como `lang` e a página exibida será a `index.php`, pois você definiu isso:

```
'/(?P<lang>\S+)' => 'index.php'
```

Como está definindo que `lang` será um elemento do *path*, o ideal é que você delimite seu valor com o caractere delimitador do *path*: a barra, `/`. Para isso, uma forma de implementar seria definir que `lang` pode ser qualquer coisa exceto a barra:

```
(?P<lang>[^/]+)
```

E, desta forma, apenas `en` será considerado `lang` na URL `/en/quem-somos`.

Comment: Boa tarde!!! Funcionou perfeitamente!!!!!
Obrigado pela disposição e pela ajuda.